# Laravel не отображаются изображения на стороннем ресурсе

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, apache, laravel-8

Есть сайт который написан с использованием laravel 8, картинки хранятся в папке `http://домен.ру/storage/folder/image.jpg` на самом сайте картинки отображаются нормально, но когда я пытаюсь вставить прямую ссылку в тег img на стороннем ресурсе то изображение не подгружается (код ошибки 499), хотя копируешь ссылку в адресную строку все открывает.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли у Laravel защита на отображения картинок на сторонних ресурсов? Или проблема в чем то другом? Спасибо.

Comment: мне кажется, что проблема с сервером. по идее, это nginx/apach не выдаёт картинки сторонним ресурсам

Comment: Вероятно с правами к папке storage проблема. Была такая проблема, мне вроде помогло ```sudo chmod -R 777 storage``` в папке с проектом. За безопасность такого использования не скажу, возможно опасно такое прописывать на продакшене

Comment: Может быть это из-за того что сторонний сайт пытается получить изображения по протоколу https хотя основной не имеет защищенного соединения?

Comment: Вполне может быть что, вследствие HTTP 499 кода, нельзя запрашивать изображения откуда-либо кроме сервера, где они размещены.

Comment: возможно этот ответ вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973304/possible-reason-for-nginx-499-error-codes